# replaceAll method in java

Tags: compiler-errors, compilation

I have a problem about using replaceAll method in my java app.
I think there is a compile error, and the code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String Str = " Welcome to Itpro.com please visit programming.itpro.com";
    System.out.println(Str.replaceAll(".com", ".net"));
}
```

and output is:

```
We.nete to Itpro.net please visit programming.itpro.net
```

welcome word has changed to `we.nete` and this is not correct.

When I change c letter in welcome word to capital C in str, everything is ok

I dont know what i do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter passed to `String#replaceAll()` will be interpreted as a regular expression pattern.  As the character `.` means any single letter, therefore `.com` will also match to `Welcome`.  To get the behavior you want, you need to escape the dot with backslash:

```java
String str = "Welcome to Itpro.com please visit programming.itpro.com";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\.com", ".net"));
```

Comment: not no bro .appreciate that

Comment: I changed checkmark to green